# How to handle <embed> tag inside Android TextView

Tags: android, html, youtube, textview

I have `TextViews` inside `ListView`, each `TextView` receive its text from `Html.fromHtml` function, How can I handle `<embed>` tags to watch YouTube videos from `TextView`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't - `TextViews` only support a small subset of `HTML` for simple formatting, like `<b>` and `<i>`.

You need to use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for complex content.

Comment: So there no other options?I can't use WebView's.

Comment: @Alex you could use MediaPlayer and/or VideoView, but honestly they're not a lot easier than a WebView.  TextViews will only handle formatted text and links - they're not meant for complex content.